# What does magic protect do in Bit Dungeon?

Tags: bit-dungeon

There are many items in Bit Dungeon that give you magic protect and I don't see how it affect the playing of the game.

Comment: @SaintWacko that's what I meant sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a stat I haven't seen, you're misreading it. This stat is not Magic *Prot*, but Magic *Proc*. Magic Proc is the chance to activate your magic power when attacking.